# Cloud Functions database event always contains empty data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue with my cloud functions where in all my database events all return empty. For example, in the following event the event.data.val() would return null. I am doing an update operation and have tested the update by testing the cloud function using the shell as well as after deploying.

```
export const createSubscription = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/subscription').onWrite( event => {
  if(!event.data.val()) {
      return;
  }
});
```

But I can easily hook into the auth.user() events like the following and receive the data.

```
export const createStripeUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  const user = event.data;
});
```

Edit: Passing data into the collection for example like the one below on the emulator console

```
createSubscription({
   testKey: 'testValue'
})
```

or the following on from my frontend

```
db.ref(`/users/23213213213/subscription`).update({ testKey: 'testValue'});
```

would return null on the function.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific about exactly what database write you are performing that should put some data in the event, but does not?

Comment: @DougStevenson just updated the question

Comment: You still haven't said anything about what and where exactly you're writing to the database that you expect to trigger your function.

Comment: i was adding an object. Let me specify that again

Comment: One thing - you're not invoking the emulator function correctly for an onWrite.  It takes two arguments, one with the data before, and the other with the new data.  myDatabaseFunction({before: 'old_data', after: 'new_data' })  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Answer (score 0):

DougStevenson is correct.  For the .onCreate() you would be doing it correct wit a myDatabaseFunction('new_data').

With the .onWrite() you need to pass in the before and after like my example below.

You may have got stuck were I did.  Note that I have a curly bracket around the before and after the final JSON.  It didn't work properly without them.

addComment({before: {"comment":"before comment","role":"guest"}, after:{"comment":"After Comment","role":"guest"}})

Hope my example helps a bit more than a generic string parameter.

Good Luck!